# What is this game (on the bottom)?

Tags: identify-this-game

Trying to figure out what game is circled in the bottom of this image. Would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: It looks like there's at least a bit more information on that page? Maybe at least a company name or something?

Comment: I don't have anything other than this picture

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's [Rock Me Archimedes](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/136554/rock-me-archimedes). The page is from Target's Black Friday 2017 Toy Catalog.

[image: Full picture of the page]